# Get the implemented type from a Generic Base Class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, base-class

I may of worded the title completely wrong, but basically, I have the following base class:

```
public class ScheduleableService<T> : ServiceBase
        where T : IJob
{
        var x = typeof(T);
}
```

The implementation of this is something like:

```
public class MyScheduledService: ScheduleableService<MyScheduledJob>
{
    //MyScheduledJob implements IJob
}
```

Basically, what I need, is in my base class ScheduleableService, to be able to get hold of the MyScheduledService type-
Is there any way I can do this without passing it in.

The following works, however is ugly.....

```
public class ScheduleableService<T, S> : ServiceBase
    where T : IJob
    where S : ServiceBase
{

    var x = typeof(T);
    var y = typeof(S);
}
```

implementation:

```
public class MyScheduledService: ScheduleableService<MyScheduledJob,
                                                     MyScheduledService>
{
    //MyScheduledJob implements IJob
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want access to the *members* of `MyScheduledService` from within `ScheduleableService<T>`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`this.GetType()` or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
MyScheduledService svc = this as MyScheduledService;
if (svc != null)
{
    // it is a MyScheduledService, and you can work with svc
}
```

But why would you need to do this?  It possibly points to a deficiency in your design.  The base class should never need to know anything about derived types.